# Compute $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{32}$ using residue theory.

Tags: complex-analysis

How does one use residues to compute
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{32}?$$

I do not understand the explanation below as it's a little light on details. It's my first time seeing the material:

[image: example]

I understood the prior examples but I don't understand how to evaluate the residues in this example. Specifically, how does one go from $\operatorname{Res}[H(z),0] + \sum \operatorname{Res}[H(z),n+1/2]$ to $\frac{\pi^3}{32}$?

Comment: It says "all of the above examples"... did you understand the above examples?  If not, that is where you should start.  If you did understand them then please state in your question exactly which bit you are having trouble with.

Comment: @David. Thanks for your comments, I've updated my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$H(z)=\frac{\pi\sec(\pi z)}{z^3}\ .$$
The singularity at the origin is a pole of order $3$ with residue
$$\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\bigl(z^3H(z)\bigr)\Bigg|_{z\to0}
  =\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\bigl(\pi\sec(\pi z)\bigr)\Bigg|_{z\to0}\ .$$
Bit of work doing the differentiation, but should not be too bad.

There are also singularities of $\sec(\pi z)$ at the points where $\cos(\pi z)=0$, that is, $z=n+\frac12$.  These are all simple poles and we can use the $p/q'$ formula to find the residue: since
$$H(z)=\frac{\pi z^{-3}}{\cos(\pi z)}$$
the residue is
$$\frac{\pi z^{-3}}{-\pi\sin(\pi z)}\Bigg|_{z=n+\frac12}\ .$$
See if you can take it from here.

**Just noticed**. . .

- Some of the poles will be on the contour stated in your book, which will really mess things up.  I think they should have taken $N(1+i)$ etc.
- Looks to me as if they also got the residue wrong. . .